MOSFET used as switch, voltage drops to 0V when load applied
I have a simple circuit board that breaks out an ESP32. It has some inputs and then multiple channels of outputs which are MOSFETs switching 12V. The board voltage is 12V and the ESP32 is powered via a buck. I had this board designed by someone and the brief was that each 12V channel just needed to switch 12V on or off and handle less than 2A in current. The loads vary but are mostly inductive loads only drawing mA. For example computer fans and small coils briefly when releasing latches.
On the bench the board works as intended. Each channel switches on and off and supplies 12V. However, when I apply a load i.e. a computer fan, the voltage drops to 0.7V. I don't know enough to know why this would be happening.
Below is the circuit diagram, where:

Channel1 is 3.3V signal from ESP32
VCC is 12V
Q1 is FDN360P
Q3 is BC849CLT1G
D1 is SMAZ10-13-F
F1 is a fuse

I have two boards with multiple channels/mosfets which all have the same behavour so I am inclinded to think not a faulty FET
I really need to finish this project and if I can't salvage this I will have to redsign a new board with a switch circuit I know works. But I am really hoping I can make this work. Is the circuit correct? Can I modify it within the existing footprint? 


What value is D1? Have you measured how much current flows into the fan when it is directly connected to a 12 volt supply? Is the fuse still OK? An inductive load requires that the drain of the pass-transistor is protected by a Zener diode to avoid damage. Does the circuit still work on a resistive 30 ohm (approx.) load?

Functionally your circuit looks like it should work, and you know it works with no load, so we need more details about it in operation. Check Q1's gate-drain and source voltage to see if it's operating. Check the base collector and emitter of Q2. Maybe try a smaller load and see if you get different results.

@Andyaka Sorry I have edited the question and added D1 in. The fan draws 110mA. Fuse is fine and same behaviour across multiple identical circuits on the board. Is shorting the load with a 30ohm resistor a valid test? If so - same result voltage drops to almost 0V

What does the incoming 12 volts look like in terms of voltage both before the MOSFET is operated and when operated. Maybe your incoming supply is too weak? I didn't suggest shorting the load with 30 ohm I suggested only the 30 ohm load and no fan.

@LordTeddy Q1 source is ~12V  but drain voltage is not going very low, 11.6V when active. Base of transistor is 3.3V, emitter read 2.45V. All measured when active (3.3V applied to Channel 1). My knowledge is basic with this stuff so let me know if I am measuring something wrong. I tried just powering a LED and it could barely run it. Voltage dropped to 2.5V

"Q1 source is ~12V but drain voltage is not going very low, 11.6V when active."    I am not sure what the problem is, since 11.6V is only 0.4V below +12V, which is good.  You want node CH1+ to be as close to the VCC voltage as possible, so CH1+=11.6V when VCC=12V is actually a good result.

"Q1 source is ~12V but drain voltage is not going very low, 11.6V when active."  Did you mean the collector of Q3 is not going very low?  Then that would explain your problems.  Check D1, it may have been installed with reversed polarity.

If, however, D1 is installed correctly, then: perhaps the load you are using to test this has a high in-rush current that causes the problem. You could test this by connecting the load to the CH1+ pin via a switch, turn the switch OFF, then put a HI on CHANNEL 1, confirm the voltage at CH1+ is what you expect (~12V), then close the switch. Does the load, in this the fan, start OK? What does the voltage at CH1 do? It would be even better to capture CH1 voltage on a scope.

@FabioBarone  thank you. Great pick up. The diodes had been placed backwards. I reversed them and now everything is working as intended.


Q1 source is ~12V but drain voltage is not going very low, 11.6V when active.

Did you mean the collector of Q3 is not going very low? If that is the case, then that would explain your problems. Check D1, it may have been installed with reversed polarity (installed backwards).

YES. Thank you, this worked. I found that the diodes had been placed backwards. I reversed them and now the circuit is working as intended. Thank you
